# extracting Wix object properties

Tags: php

I'm new to Wix and I'm working on a desktop app.

When I create a new Wix object:

```
$wix = new Wix()
```

I get this:

```
object(Wix)#8 (2) { ["appId":"Wix":private]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ["secret":"Wix":private]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }
```

I want to extract the appID and since it's a private property, If I try to access it I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Wix::$appId
```

So I tried casting the object to an array and I now get this:

```
array(2) { ["WixappId"]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" ["Wixsecret"]=> string(36) "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" }
```

But this is a weird array I can't seem to access

Can anyone tell me how I can access this type of array?

Thank you

Comment: whats weird about the array?

Comment: Have you tried `$wix->getAppId()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into the Wix sdk, and found the [class object](https://github.com/wix/wix-sdk-sample-app-php/blob/master/php-demo-blog/php5/lib/Wix.php). You can access the app ID with

```
$wix->getAppId();
```

If you need to access the secret, use:

```
$wix->getSecret();
```